# How to obtain array from IList inteface

Tags: c#, arrays, collections

Is that possible in C# to obtain array from System.Collections.IList interface without using Generics?

**EDIT**: I need some approach for converting collection to array. My collection is assigned to IList. Is that possible to do that? I don't know real implementation of my collection so I can't do e.g. like this
  int[] arr = (ArrayList)list.ToArray();

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. Please be more specific.

Comment: CopyTo() ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.copyto.aspx

Comment: @Jon Skeet please see my edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.copyto.aspx) method:

```
IList list = new List<string>(new[] { "one", "two", "three" });
string[] array = new string[list.Count];
list.CopyTo(array, 0);
```

Comment: @Neil: yes, the source list is generic, but it is used only through the non-generic `IList` interface.

Comment: To emphasise Fredrik's point - you can pretty much ignore everything to the right of the `=` in the first line; the important thing here is "we have an `IList` named `list`"